# Why does Extern-C return POD and constructed types differently?

Tags: c++, c

On Win32 I just noticed that making a struct non-POD causes the signature of functions that return the struct by value to change.

Why is this? And doesn't that mean C could not declare the function signature of the extern-C function?

For instance if the preprocessor sees __cplusplus and so slips in a constructor or two along with some other member functions yielding a struct with an identical layout. Then why should that matter in this way?

Comment: Hm, because C only knows PODs, so any non-POD is not C compatible?

Comment: @Deduplicator, extern "C" return should do so as POD then.

Comment: So, `extern "C"` should magically make a non-POD a POD? Nice trick that. Would be nice to have such magic help, yes.

Comment: ^If the function is extern "C" it would make sense if it behaved like C. So while it's probably too late for that, yes it should. Either that or not allow it.

EDIT: For instance if a struct is extern "C" then things C cannot do are not allowed. But not for functions. Not on Win32 (VS2005) at any rate (but I agree, it would be cool if the behavior of the struct changed to accommodate as much C++ as possible.)

Comment: So, you want a hard error? Or a different reinterpretation of your code? IMHO, both would actually have been more reasonable design decisions. (Probably the compiler decided)

Comment: I don't think there is a clear interpretation. If so that would be interesting to add to an answer. A hard error would definitely be preferred over a non-POD function signature--and seems to me like that would be more correct. IMHO it's a bug in the compiler. The compiler hard errors for an extern "C" struct so it should for functions too. It's worth noting that it's an older compiler.

EDITED: For intance should an extern "C" function allow references in its argument list? If not then the return should be straight POD too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the ultimate answer can only be given by whoever defined the ABI, but the probable reason is that C copies structs by just copying memory, but for non-PODs, such memory copying *may* not work correctly. And the information needed to decide whether a memcpy is valid may be in a different file, and even if all information is available, the compiler may not be able to decide it (it is equivalent to the halting problem). Therefore the ABI designer probably decided to just assume that it is not possible for non-PODs (even if in the given case it might be actually provable, it's just not worth the effort to try).

Also note that formally, adding a member function makes the type different in C++, and having one declaration with and another without that member function makes your code technically undefined behaviour even if this affects neither layout nor PODness of the class (like a non-virtual non-special member function).

Comment: Yes. I just thought this is an interesting question. The function is extern "C" so it seems like it should blindly copy by value, and leave the details to the application programmers to fret over.

Comment: I will go ahead and mark this as a tentative solution, even though I'd like to see more thoughts generated on the subject myself. The gist here is the behavior is implementation dependent. That's the one thing I wanted to find out by asking (it seems to me that it's an error on the compiler to both allow it and not return as if POD)

Comment: @MickP.: You can implement an `extern "C"` function in C++ code, and call it from other C++ code. In most ABIs (I don't know of Win32, though) all `extern "C"` means in practice is to not mangle the name, which may be useful for other purposes than interfacing with C (e.g. for use with tools which don't understand C++ name mangling, but don't actually call the function and therefore don't care about calling conventions). Therefore it may be useful to be able to safely call any `extern "C"` function from C++ code even if it has no C-compatible interface.